# java console menu

Tags: java, menu, console, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a java console menu. however, my jre doesn't support "Scanner". What is the walk around to this problem?

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
```

Comment: Scanner should be available in Java 1.5 or newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
```